# I want to add new column that contains html files in solr indexer using nutch 1.17 version

Tags: nutch

I want to add new column that contains htmls files(raw html files).May I know what configurations changes are required.I read segment reader that contains content folder but output is text file i want to index the htmls files in a column.May I know how could I achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to face special character issues in raw HTML when indexing in Solr. Anyhow, first you should1 customize index-basic plugin in Nutch. Its class name is BasicIndexingFilter.java. Update this class with followings:

```
String htmlcontent = parse.getData();
doc.add("htmlContent", StringUtil.cleanField(htmlcontent));
```

After this, you also have to add a field with Solr Schem "htmlContent". Hopefully it will solve your issue.

There may be others options also for this task.

I found another option as commented that works best. Use nutch CLI

```
bin/nutch index crawldb-path -dir segments-directory -addBinarycontent -base64
```

Comment: I solved it by using bin/nutch index crawldb-path -dir segments-directory -addBinarycontent -base64  .so it convert the raw content which is stored in content folder and while indexing it converts into base64 after indexing i decoded base64 and I recieved all types files which is stored in segemen folder one of the file is html file,

Comment: `parse.getData()` returns a Java object of type [ParseData](https://nutch.apache.org/apidocs/apidocs-1.17/org/apache/nutch/parse/ParseData.html) which is not the plain HTML but contains results of the parsing: title, outlinks and metadata. The way outlined by @RaviKiran is the correct way to go.

Comment: @SebastianNagel bin/nutch index crawldb-path -dir segments-directory -addBinarycontent -base64

Comment: @SebastianNagel I have commented the command hope it understands for you.for further u can go througth documentation.

Comment: @Shafiq can share your profile(linkedin) because we both are working on same task.so it helps for better result.

Comment: I think this will give access to you. https://www.linkedin.com/in/muhammad-shafiq-57a8a72b/